# cs50 tideman, lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

Tags: c

I am attempting to solve the [CS50 tideman assignment](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/psets/3/tideman/).

When I check my code, it returns:

```
lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:( lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
```

Everything else works for my code. Ive looked through similar examples, however the solutions to their problems looked quite similar to my code

```
'''
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            printf("%i", preferences[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
int pairs_preference(int i)
{
    int w = pairs[i].winner;
    int l = pairs[i].loser;
    return preferences[w][l];
}

void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = pair_count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int min_votes = pairs_preference(i);
        int min_votes_index = i;
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            int pair_value = pairs_preference(j);
            if (pair_value < min_votes)
            {
                min_votes = pair_value;
                min_votes_index = j;
            }
        }
        pair temp = pairs[i];
        pairs[i] = pairs[min_votes_index];
        pairs[min_votes_index] = temp;
    }
    return;
}

bool cycle(int w, int l)
{
    if (w == l)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (locked[l][i] == true && cycle(i, w) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int w = pairs[i].winner;
        int l = pairs[i].loser;
        if (!cycle(w, l))
        {
            locked[w][l] = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int w = 0; w < candidate_count; w++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < candidate_count; l++)
        {
            if (locked[l][w] == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (l == candidate_count - 1)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[w]);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
'''
```

Comment: In the function `cycle`, I believe the function call `cycle(i, w)` should be `cycle(w, i)`.